# Why do we need session , when we already have cookies?

Tags: session, url, cookies

I am new to web application , I am learning cookies and session, I understand HTTP is stateless protocol to make it stateful we use cookies at client side and session at server side.

1. When user requests a webpage it sends all the cookies available for that 
   browser on the PC.
2. If any one of the cookie matches with server side database , the server 
   shows the data , else sends set cookie with a session iD(optional to send 
   create session and send the session ID).

   a. If server sends set cookie the client sends cookie in all respective 
      requests with the session id , only if the domain name matches with the 
      server to which the client sent .

Now my doubt is suppose I am working on an e-commerce site. And the server sends the number of items added to the cart till the user is not logging out , now it can be done using cookie alone why do we need session at all?

Is there something I am not understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

- There may be, and probably is, sensitive data in that session, e.g. the user's **id**, identifying who the user is. If you just stored the user's id in a cookie, the user could manipulate it and easily pose as anyone else. There are of course ways to mitigate that, but simply not allowing the user to futz with the cookie contents (because it's just a meaningless session id) is the simplest.
- It allows the server to manage session state; e.g. if a user suspects somebody is logged in as them on another device, they can invalidate *all other sessions* ("log me out everywhere" functionality).
- You may be storing *a lot* of data, and sending it back and forth in a cookie on every request can become rather wasteful.
- You may want to associate something like a shopping basket with the user's account, not just the user's browser, so when they log in on another device their shopping cart is following them around.

Yes, there are also perfectly fine cases were storing information just in a cookie is fine and preferable, especially since that allows you to scale your server more easily to a cluster of servers without having to worry about where the session information is stored. It depends on what information exactly you are storing.

Comment: what about cookies encryption?

Comment: You can use *signed* cookies, which stores information in plaintext in the cookie but prevents manipulation. Or you encrypt the cookie, which prevents reading *and* manipulation. In theory the encryption _could_ be broken if weak enough, since an attacker can do offline brute force attacks at their leisure; but in practice it's probably fine. So yes, that provides an alternative for the first point. But the others remain.

Comment: but it brings stateless servers, so in big scale saves tons of money and easy architecture and development.

Comment: Sure. If you don't need the other points, that's definitely a big plus.

Answer (score 4):

These are separate concepts:

- Cookie - Browser sends this with every request automatically
- Header - Part of a HTTP request, the browser will only send data here if instructed.
- Access token - Contains secret which may be a JWT (and identify the user) or a random set of characters
- Session - a token bound to a user + device that authenticates the user. If the user doesn't have an access token, they can use the session to get a new token.

You can see that Cookie/Header are the **where** and access token/session token are the **what**.

The user needs to authenticate in your service. That means you need to be able to identify the user. That may be done with a JWT, session token, IP address, a signature, etc... And that is separate from how this data is transmitted to the service from the user.

So when you say **why do you I need session when the user has cookies**, these are totally unrelated. The session id may be saved in a cookie, that's just one option.

Whether or not the session id in a cookie corresponds to actual data on the server side is another completely separate question. Should the session token be a encrypted (or signed) object, like a **JWT** which contains user identifying information, or should that data be saved in a server side DB, and only transmit a random-string identifier. Who knows?

The answer is going to be based on what's critical for your application. Generally speaking, session tracking on the server side is a legacy concept, and the new hotness (which is old now), is to make the sessionId a **JWT** saved a HTTP Only cookie for security. And then passed on every request.

Lot's of services have sessions and access token management baked in, and for a working example and more about tokens, check out [any one of many knowledge bases](https://authress.io/knowledge-base).

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern is

- the cookie contains only a unique session identifier (but no useful information itself)
- the session storage (server-side) contains the associated data for this session. This can be a) very big and b) hidden from the user/browser and c) trustworthy (because the user cannot just modify it in the browser)

Comment: and d) examined by server-side processing for metrics/analytics and other interesting things

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to use sessions because the actual values are hidden from the client, and you control when the data expires and becomes invalid. If it was all based on cookies, a user (or hacker) could manipulate their cookie data and then play requests to your site.